# Multiple inheritance from a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming

I want to have a general storage class that can store variety of objects, I don't want to use a heterogeneous container class that stores all of them. I thought of creating a templated storage class, and create a general storage class that inherits from this metaclasses with different types:

```
template<typename Type>
struct SingleInterface
{
public:
    SingleInterface() = default;
    virtual ~SingleInterface() = default;
    SingleInterface(const SingleInterface &) = default;
    SingleInterface & operator=(const SingleInterface &) = default;
    SingleInterface(SingleInterface &&) = default;
    SingleInterface & operator=(SingleInterface &&) = default;

    void get(const std::string & keyword, Type * ptr)
    {
        // implementation
    }

};
```

My general class as below:

```
class MutliInterface: public SingleInterface<double>, SingleInterface<int>
{
public:
    MutliInterface() = default;
    virtual ~MutliInterface() = default;
};
```

when I create a MutliInterface class, I get the following error:

```
MutliInterface interface;
double *v;
interface.get("test", v);
```

> 'get' is ambiguous '

Comment: doesn't Type in get method solve the ambiguity ???   void get(const std::string & keyword, Type * ptr)

Answer (score 4):

Expose both overloads with a `using` statement in the derived class:

```
class MutliInterface: public SingleInterface<double>, SingleInterface<int>
{
public:
    MutliInterface() = default;
    virtual ~MutliInterface() = default;
    using SingleInterface<double>::get;
    using SingleInterface<int>::get;
};
```

It's ambiguous because of [class.member.lookup] that basically says that when the name of a function `get` isn't found immediately in the class `MutliInterface`, a set of candidate functions is created using the class' base classes. However, the functions must be identical otherwise it's ambiguous (and here they are NOT identical).

When we use the `using` keyword here, we shortcut all that and both overloads are immediately accessible from the derived class.